# What happens inside of this condition statement? while (a = foo(bar))

Tags: c

It may sounds silly, but I want to know the happening when I execute while(a = function(b)){}.

Suppose we got NULL for the return value of read_command_stream.

Can I get out of the loop?

```
while ((command = read_command_stream (command_stream)))
{
    if (print_tree)
    {
        printf("# %d\n", command_number++);
        print_command (command);
    }
    else
    {
        last_command = command;
        execute_command(command, time_travel);
    }
}
```

#### struct command

```
struct command
{
  enum command_type type;

  // Exit status, or -1 if not known (e.g., because it has not exited yet).
  int status;

  // I/O redirections, or null if none.
  char *input;
  char *output;

  union
  {
    // for AND_COMMAND, SEQUENCE_COMMAND, OR_COMMAND, PIPE_COMMAND:
    struct command *command[2];

    // for SIMPLE_COMMAND:
    char **word;

    // for SUBSHELL_COMMAND:
    struct command *subshell_command;
  } u;
};
```

Comment: NULL is 0 so it's condition that breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Why not test it and see what happens?

Comment: Wait. So first command gets value of NULL.

Comment: The `while` loop will exit as soon as `read_command_stream` returns a zero value, including `NULL`. `command` will be assigned the return value, so when the loop exits, `command` will have the zero or NULL value.

Comment: So does compiler evaluates command again?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "evaluates command". Every time that expression is encountered, the return value of `read_command_stream` is assigned to `command`. Then the while will exit if this value is `0` (or `NULL` which is the same value as `0`). It probably is optimized such that it doesn't have to read the value back out of `command` since it already knows the value having been returned from `read_command_stream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax says:

```
while (expression) { ... }
```

and `expression` can be a lot.
It can be:

- a constant: `while (1) { ... }`
- the result of a comparison: `while (a < b) { ... }`
- some boolean construct: : `while (a < b && c < d ) { ... }`
- the resulting expression from an assignment: `while (*dst++ = *src++) {;}`
- and the assignment can also involve function calls: `while((ch = getc()) != EOF) { ... }`
- a plain variable: `while(i) ( ...)`
- an expression based on the evaluation of a plain variable  : `while (i--) { ... }` (even with side effects!)
- a pointer expression: : `while (*++argv) { ... }`

Now, in the case of an integer expression, the expression is checked for *not equal to zero*. For pointer expressions, it is checked against *not equal to NULL*. That's all.

The crux of this is that in C, **even an assignment is an expression**, so you can write:

```
a = b = c;
```

or even:
    a = b = c = d;

But, since an assignment is also an expression, you could even write:

```
while ( a = b = c = d) { ... }
```

Comment: `i--` is not a plain variable, it is not even an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` evaluates to whatever it sets the variable to, so if you do something like
`var = 0`
This evaluates to 0 and if it was in a while loop would break out.

Also remember `NULL` is just 0 (though it's not guaranteed) so something returning `NULL` will have the same effect to break out of a loop. Generally it's a bad idea to use an `=` as a condition and good compilers will warn you about it.

Comment: = returns? I thought it's an operator.

Comment: Yes = returns thats how you can chain them like `a = b = 1`

Comment: The value of the assignment expression is evaluated in terms of the if condition, and a decision is made whether to run the loop or not.  `=` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I believe operators don't return, just b=1 evaluates to right operand and so on.

Comment: @aaronman, no zubergu isn't wrong.  There is a specific meaning behind `return` and `=` does not return anything.  An (assignment) expression evaluates to a value.

Comment: @jamessan so than what is `func()` that evaluates to something, that's what returning is, in the case of `=` it's hidden from you, but if you use a language like c++ you can overload it and of course the overload does return something

Comment: @aaronman Look it up where? The C standard consistently uses “returns” for a function and “evaluates to” for an expression. What other document are we supposed to look it up in, according to you?

Comment: @PascalCuoq I guess the standard uses the wording you say

Comment: @zubergu sorry I dismissed your comment, because from the first one I thought you were implying that `a = b = 1` can't be done

Comment: @jamessan I've amended my wording

Answer (score 0):

Null is supposed to be zero unless otherwise specified on your system/compiler.  Therefore, the loop terminates.